# Make a variable immutable

Tags: php

Is there any way to make my variable immutable so I can call my class instance with the same variable name in my `foreach` anywhere?

I'm calling `$user->count()` after `foreach` but the `$user` variable has been modified by `foreach` and its throwing some error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::count() in C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\test.php:48 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\test.php on line 48

The implementation is below:

```
<?php 
include 'connection.php'; 

class Collection {
  public $items;
  public function __construct ($items = []) {
    $this->items = $items;
  }
  public function get() {
    $object = $this->items;
    return $object;
  }

  public function count() {
    return count($this->items);
  }

}


class User extends Collection {

}

class Post extends Collection {

}

$stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM users_account");
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$user = new User($row);
$users = $user->get();

$stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts");
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$post = new Post($row);
$posts = $post->get();


foreach ($users as $user) {
  echo $user->username.'<br />';
}

echo $user->count();

echo "<hr />";

foreach ($posts as $post) {
  echo $post->body.'<br />';
}

echo $post->count();
```

Comment: No, AFAIK PHP doesn't have immutable variables. Don't reuse variable names like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply use a different variable name?  It's a far easier solution that makes for more readable code.

```
class Collection
{
    protected $items; // protected because having strong encapsulation is good

    public function __construct($items = [])
    {
        $this->items = $items;
    }

    public function get()
    {
        return $this->items; // no need to put it in a separate variable if you're simply returning
    }

    public function count()
    {
        return count($this->items);
    }
}

class User extends Collection {}

// blah blah blah

$users = new User($row);
$userList = $users->get();

foreach ($userList as $user) {
    // do work
}
```

Comment: >protected
>strong encapsulation
lmfao